# JavaScript nasted default parameters

Tags: javascript, javascriptcore, default-parameters, destructuring

Lets say I want to process some property **x** of objects in collection **array**. But collection may contain objects without such property or even **undefined**s. For example

```
let array = [
  {x: 1},
  {x: 2},
  {},
  {x: 4},
  undefined
]
```

The idea is protect my self from such edge cases with default parameter. Let it be **0**. I was trying to solve this as

```
array.map(({x: x = 0}) => process(x))
```

But it fails on **undefined**. Is there any way to solve this issue with default parameters and destructuring without writing check/set code inside of map function?

Comment: It fails for the same reason this would `var x; x.hi = 10;`. Its trying to access/write a property of an un-assigned variable, most likely throwing a `TypeError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the default object a default value

```
array.map(({x : x = 0} = 0) => process(x));
```

Comment: Yes, this one works. Same result if
   array.map(({x : x = 0} = {}) => process(x));
I don't understand exactly why this works, but undefined are handled perfectly. If there would be any solution for if not to crash on null - I would be 100% happy :)

Comment: Actually works not just = 0 or = {}, but = anything but null and undefined. Don't now why...

Comment: The reason is that it makes default parameter mechanism starts to work and when it met undefined - it replaces it with some value any trying to find field **x** on that value. This is grate but petty that it fails on **null** :(

Comment: Would have to dive in destructuring some more to see how to handle nulls. Without destructuring, something like  `array.map( x=> process((x || {}).x || 0));` could be used, but that's not the goal of course :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` before `.map` in order to clean all [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values like `null`, `0`, `''`, `false`

```
array = array
    .filter((el) => el)
    .map(({x: x = 0}) => process(x));
```

[`Example`](http://www.es6fiddle.net/igxpooo8/)

In [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) there is good description

> Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or **undefined** is
>   passed.

so `null` is value., so if you pass `null` to function default value does not used, for example

```
function test(x = 10) {
    console.log(x);
}

test(undefined); // 10
test();          // 10
test(null);      // null
test(0);         // 0
test('');        // ''
```

[`Example`](http://www.es6fiddle.net/igxqtjy7/)